# JQuery Modal Dialog does not open or display

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog

I am using a jquery dialog, but the dialog.open() does not display the dialog.  (The site only works with IE 7 & 8, so I cannot see if the dialog is in fact displayed.)

I have ensured that these dependencies are available:jquery-ui.css; jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js; https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js

In the markup: I creates the dialog in the document ready method:

var $dialog;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $dialog = $("#dialog")
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'My Modal Dialog',
            position: 'center',
            modal: true,
            closeOnEscape: true,
            buttons: [{ text: "Close", click: function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } }]
        });
});
```

Another javascript function contains these lines to "open' the dialog.  When I inspect the dialog, it is an Object, but I never see it.

```
function showDialog() {
   $dialog.html("Hello World");
   $dialog.dialog('open');
}
```

The code looks sound, and in another project I've worked on, works without a hitch.  So that leaves me to think that it IS opening, but I can't see it for some reason.  Has anyone encountered this, or found a solution to this?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

Have you created parent element:

```
<div id="dialog">..
```

in document ?

Comment: I've not used a parent element, in this example or in the markup of the page where this same code did work.  Also, I've not seen other "successful" implementations of the jQuery dialog use a parent element.  How would I designate an element as the parent of $dialog?

Comment: here is written: `$dialog = $("#dialog")` - create dialog from element with id "dialog". You need to have `<div id="dialog"></div>` anywhere in your body.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem.  (I wonder why the dialog was revealed as a valid OBJECT in my calling function?)